# Java use stream() and filter() to get running total of nested map

Tags: java

suppose I have a map whose key is also a map

```
Map<Map<String, Integer>, Integer>
```

I want to calculate the running sum for the values of the outer map
if the outer map's key's values match a given

I have the following code

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main{
     public static void main(String []args){
        Map<Map<String, Integer>, Integer> courses = new HashMap<Map<String,Integer>,Integer>();
        
        Map<String,Integer> temp = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        temp.put("CS 111", 1);
        
        Map<String,Integer> temp2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        temp2.put("CS 222", 2);
        
        Map<String,Integer> temp3 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        temp2.put("CS 333", 1);
        
        courses.put(temp, 3);
        courses.put(temp2, 5);
        courses.put(temp3, 7);
        
        //sum should be 10
        int sum = courses.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .filter(m ->m.getKey()
                     .stream()
                     .anyMatch(t->t.getValue()==1)
               .reduce(0,Integer::sum));
     }
}
```

Comment: It is very unusual (and probably inefficient and unreadable) to use a Map as a key. What if the inner map has multiple entries? If the inner map can only have one entry, why not make the key an Entry instead of a Map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your filter you can use `Map.values()` to get the values of the map which makes it a bit more readable. After filtering you can use `Stream.mapToInt` which can be sumed easily. Example:

```
Map<Map<String,Integer>, Integer> myMap = 
    Map.of(
            Map.of("CS 111", 1), 3,
            Map.of("CS 222", 2), 5,
            Map.of("CS 333", 1), 7
    );

int sum = myMap.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .filter(e -> e.getKey().containsValue(1))
               .mapToInt(Map.Entry::getValue).sum();

System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: @Eritrean e.getKey().values().contains(1)) can be replaced with just e.getKey().containsValue(1) if you want to save a few characters.

Comment: @HomeworkHopper Thanks. It is indeed better and clear.